# ReactJS Using styles within classComponent

Tags: reactjs

Good day. I'm having trouble figuring out how to use styles within classComponent. Here is the code:

```
const image = require('../../static/images/auth_bg.jpg');
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        paddingTop: theme.spacing(15),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
    btn_forgot: {
        color: '#000',
        textDecorator: 'none'
    },
    btn_register: {
        color: '#000',
        textDecorator: 'none'
    },
    bg: {
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
        backgroundSize: "cover",
    },
}));

class SignIn extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // console.log(image);
        const { classes } = useStyles;
        return (
            <div className={classes.bg}>
                <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs" pt={5}>
                    <CssBaseline/>
                    <div className={classes.paper}>
                        <Typography
                            component="h1"
                            variant="h5"
                            style={{color: 'white'}}
                        >
                            Sign in
                        </Typography>
                        <form className={classes.form}>
                            <MyEmailField/>
                            <MyPasswordField
                                label="Password"
                            />
                            <Button
                                type="submit"
                                fullWidth
                                variant="contained"
                                color="default"
                                className={classes.submit}
                            >
                                Sign In
                            </Button>
                            <Grid container>
                                <Grid item xs>
                                    <Link
                                        to="/reset"
                                        variant="body1"
                                        className={classes.btn_forgot}
                                        style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}
                                    >
                                        Forgot password?
                                    </Link>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item>
                                    <Link
                                        to="/register"
                                        variant="body2"
                                        className={classes  .btn_register}
                                        style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}
                                    >
                                        {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                                    </Link>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SignIn;
```

Error :

> TypeError: classes is undefined

I'm understanding something js specific incorrectly,could someone point out what that is?
Should all of the styles be imported inside of the class component or?

**SKIP**
I'm understanding something js specific incorrectly,could someone point out what that is?
Should all of the styles be imported inside of the class component or?

Comment: Assuming this is from the material library, you need to call `useStyles()`, and use the return value instead of a property of the return value `const classes = useStyles()`

Comment: Other than invoking `useStyles` incorrectly, or not at all, `useStyles` is a react hook and only compatible with functional components. Use the `withStyles` HOC instead. https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api

Answer (score 0):

Based on **Drew Reeses** answer i changed the following

```
const useStyles = theme => ({
    paper: {
        paddingTop: theme.spacing(15),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)
    },
    btn_forgot: {
        color: '#000',
        textDecorator: 'none'
    },
    btn_register: {
        color: '#000',
        textDecorator: 'none'
    },
    bg: {
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
        backgroundSize: "cover",
    },
});



export default withStyles(useStyles)(SignIn);
```